# I want to store the Python shell data into a database

Tags: python, tweepy

I am new to Python. I'm using this code to get the details of a user (in a Python shell currently).

```
import tweepy
import time
import sqlite3
import os
from datetime import datetime
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(key,secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secter)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user('<the_user_to_query_on_here>')
print ("User id: " + user.id_str)
print ("Screen_Name: " + user.screen_name)
print (user.name)
print ("Description: " + user.description)
print ("Language: " + user.lang)
print ("Account created at: " + str(user.created_at))
print ("Location: " + user.location)
print ("Time zone: " + user.time_zone)
print ("Number of tweets: " + str(user.statuses_count))
print ("Number of followers: " + str(user.followers_count))
print ("Number of Following: " + str(user.friends_count))
print ("A member of " + str(user.listed_count) + " lists.")
print ("Retreiving friends for", user.screen_name)
for friend in user.friends():
    print ("Following_Names: " + str(friend.screen_name))
```

I would like to store this information in a database so that I can retrieve it locally later. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't see how storing this string (_strings_, actually) in a database would be different from storing any other strings in a database.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problems you are getting?  I see you have already decided on sqlite, do you have a design?  If not, then that is your first step.

Comment: [This link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) might be helpful, or if you want to store in MySQL Database, check [this](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

Comment: Thanks cdarke and kevin. Yes this is my first step. I am going through the links you provided. will get back to you guys again.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks ashwani for the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLite3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sqlite3.html) that's already included in Python as a possible solution.

What you'll need to do, instead of calling `print()` to each one, assign it to a variable, then store that variable into the database.

For example, change:

```
print ("User id: " + user.id_str)
print ("Screen_Name: " + user.screen_name)
```

to

```
user_id = user.id_str
screen_same = user.screen_name
```

Then open a connection to the database (before or after as long it doesn't continously loop) and store those variables using:

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('twitter.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()
    # the following line only needed once to create the table
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Twitter(User ID, Screen Name, etc...)") 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Twitter VALUES(user_id,screen_name, etc...)")
    # or
    # you can insert user.id_str directly without assigning it to a variable
    # cur.execute("INSERT INTO Twitter VALUES(user.id_str,user.screen_name, etc...)")
```

Here's a great [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/) about SQLite3